# Force user to reboot machine with Burn

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

I have a bootloader that I created with WiX 3.6/[Burn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX#Burn) and was wondering if there was a command similar to `<ExitCode Behavior="forceReboot"/>` that would execute only on uninstall after everything was executed in the `<chain>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the ScheduleReboot action in one of your MSIs and condition the action to run on unistall. Burn will respect the restart request and inform the user a restart is required at the end.