# Unable to prompt for reboot after installation with Wix Bootstrapper project

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.7

I have a Wix Project and also a Bootstrapper. I want to prompt the user to restart after the last MSI is run.
Here is the Bootstrapper-

```
<Chain>
<MsiPackage  SourceFile=".\Some.msi" Compressed="yes" />
<MsiPackage Id="MyMsi"
              Compressed="yes"
              Cache="no"
              DisplayInternalUI="yes"
              SourceFile="$(var.MyInstaller.TargetPath)"
              Visible="no"/>
</Chain>
```

In my MSI, I have -
`<Property Id="REBOOT" Value="Force"/>`
and

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <ScheduleReboot After='InstallFinalize'>NOT REMOVE</ScheduleReboot>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But the prompt doesn't show up. In the log I can find these lines-

> Property(S): MsiRebootActionScheduled = 1

> MSI (s) (40:64) [23:52:23:990]: Value of RebootAction property is 1

> MSI (s) (40:64) [23:52:23:990]: Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: XXX x64 Installer v3.0.0.0. Product Version: 3.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: XXX. Type of System Restart: 2. Reason for Restart: 2.

> MSI (s) (40:64) [23:52:23:990]: Product: XXX x64 Installer v3.0.0.0. Restart required. The installation or update for the product required a restart for all changes to take effect.  **The restart was deferred to a later time.**

Any suggestion on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the reboot code from your MSIs and just add the one into the bootstrapper. Adding reboot into bootstrapper was answered on this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55491111/how-can-i-force-reboot-after-installation-completion-burn-bootstrapper-in-wix).

Comment: May you please elaborate on that bit more?

Comment: If you're installing more than 1 MSI from a bootstrapper just remove the reboots from the MSI and then reboot from the setup.exe after all of the MSIs are installed.

Comment: Assuming that you are pointing to <ExePackage> and ExitCode property in the Bootstrapper, I don't really have any exe in the chain of Bootstrapper.